# In how many ways can Bob donate either two of his nine shirts or one of his four pairs of pants?

Tags: combinatorics

Good afternoon, I'm confused about this question:

> Bob has $9$ shirts and $4$ pairs of pants. He gets a small tax
> break if he donates either two shirts or one pair of pants.
> In how many ways can this be done?

Do I use this equation:

$9(2) \cdot 4$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I changed it to 9(2)+4. I still dk if that is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that there are ${n\choose k}$ ways of choosing k items from a total of n. This means there are ${9\choose 2}$ ways of choosing two shirts and ${4\choose 1}$ ways of choosing the pants he can donate. Can you work it out from here?

Comment: I got 40 by adding both of the numbers. 9c2 is 36 and 4c1 is 4.

Comment: would forty be the right answer?

Comment: It's correct assuming the "either or" in the problem is exclusive as it should be.

Comment: Thank you so much